# SQL. Compare Rows and Set Values to NULL If Nonexistent

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Here is sample data:

```
|    date    |   id   |  version  |
| 2013-04-15 | 'ape'  |    1.1    |
| 2013-04-15 | 'bat'  |    2.1    |
| 2013-04-15 | 'cat'  |    3.1    |
| 2013-04-15 | 'dog'  |    4.1    |
| 2013-03-15 | 'ape'  |    1.0    |
| 2013-03-15 | 'cat'  |    3.2    |
| 2013-03-15 | 'dog'  |    3.8    |
| 2013-02-15 | 'ape'  |    0.9    |
| 2013-02-15 | 'dog'  |    3.1    |
```

The query will be determining the newest date and the second newest date. In the example this is 2013-4-15 and 2013-3-15.

I will probably find those with this code, because it is something I know:

```
DECLARE @FirstDate DATETIME
SET @FirstDate = (SELECT max(date)
              FROM mytable)

DECLARE @SecondDate DATETIME
SET @SecondDate = (SELECT max(date)
              FROM mytable
              WHERE date < @FirstDate)
```

I want output like this:

```
|    date     |   id   |  version   |   prevdate   | pversion   |
| 2013-04-15  | 'ape'  |    1.1     |  2013-03-15  |   1.0      |
| 2013-04-15  | 'bat'  |    2.1     |  2013-03-15  |   null     |
| 2013-04-15  | 'cat'  |    3.1     |  2013-03-15  |   3.2      |
| 2013-04-15  | 'dog'  |    4.1     |  2013-03-15  |   3.8      |
```

So the query finds all the rows with date = FirstDate. And for each row it will look at the date = SecondDate rows and include the version number for the rows with the same id. If there is no date = SecondDate row with the same id, return "null" or "" or 0 or something.

Comment: Do you have a column with that order of your rows?. A table has no "natural" order, so saying that you need the same order as they are on the original table is pointless

Comment: Okay, I edited it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is one way:

```
SELECT A.*, B.[date] prevdate, B.[Version] pVersion
FROM myTable A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 [date], [Version]
             FROM myTable
             WHERE [date] < A.[date]
             AND id = A.id) B
WHERE A.[date] = (SELECT MAX([date]) FROM myTable)
```

This are the results:

```
╔════════════╦═════╦═════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║    date    ║ id  ║ Version ║  prevdate  ║ pVersion ║
╠════════════╬═════╬═════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║ 2013-04-15 ║ ape ║ 1,1     ║ 2013-03-15 ║ 1        ║
║ 2013-04-15 ║ bat ║ 2,1     ║ NULL       ║ NULL     ║
║ 2013-04-15 ║ cat ║ 3,1     ║ 2013-03-15 ║ 3,2      ║
║ 2013-04-15 ║ dog ║ 4,1     ║ 2013-03-15 ║ 3,8      ║
╚════════════╩═════╩═════════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

And [**here is an sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75c3c1/1) with a demo of this.

Comment: Seems simple enough! Thanks.